# python3.4 connection.py bytes object is not callable

Tags: python, multiprocessing, scikit-learn

I'm using LogisticRegression and RandomizedSearchCV from scikit-learn and my python version is 3.4. 
However, the code throws TypeError during the multi processing:

```
Fitting 5 folds for each of 10 candidates, totalling 50 fits
[Parallel(n_jobs=8)]: Done   1 jobs       | elapsed:    1.2s
Process ForkPoolWorker-718:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/process.py", line 254, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 108, in worker
    task = get()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/pool.py", line 343, in get
    return recv()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 251, in recv
    return ForkingPickler.loads(buf.getbuffer())
TypeError: 'bytes' object is not callable
```

Here is the code for parameter optimization using randomized search ( using multi processing )

```
print("Performing parameter optimization ...")
params = \
{'penalty': ['l1', 'l2'],
'C': [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1.0, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000],
'dual': [False],
'class_weight': ['auto']}

search = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator, params,
                                        n_iter=10,
                                        scoring=scorer, n_jobs=8, refit=True,
                                        cv=StratifiedKFold(y_trains, 5), 
                                        verbose=1, random_state=1)

search.fit(X_trains, y_trains)
```

Any idea on what the problem is and how I can solve it?

Comment: So either `ForkingPicler.loads` or `buf.getbuffer` is a bytes object. Can you share your code so we can spot why that might have happened?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Tnx but how can i fix it?

Comment: @MartijnPieters just edited the question and added the parameter optimization code

Comment: Actually, given that this is happening in pickling, it's possible—in fact, it seems likely—that neither `loads` nor `getbuffer` is a bytes object, but that something has been pickled wrong. Maybe the user's class has a `__reduce__` that was supposed to be a `__getnewargs__`, or maybe there's something funky that's causing some name to refer to a class in one process but to a buffer in another, etc.

Comment: One thing to try is to manually pickle and unpickle each of the objects in the relevant call. (I'm not sure which of the two calls is relevant without more context, but you can always try them both.) Even if this is where the problem is, that _may_ not find it, but it's worth trying.

Comment: @abarnert: ah, yes, `self.__getnewargs__ = b'foo'` could do that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters where should I put this exactly?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Well, that would raise inside `dumps`, not `loads`, and in the main process instead of the worker. But, say, writing a `__reduce__` that returns a tuple of all your attributes, where the first one is a `bytes`, that would do it.

Comment: @Pooya: No, don't add that; he's suggesting something you might have done wrong in the code you haven't shown us, not something you should add to that code. At any rate, if you want more help, you have to (a) show us the code and/or (b) run the pickling tests I suggested above.

Comment: @Pooya: that's not something you want to add. I'm discussing possible ways of breaking `cPickle`.

Comment: @abarnert: yes, I wasn't paying too much attention, you are right.

Comment: @abarnert That was the whole code ( The rest are definitely not related to this issue). The exception raises on how scikit and randomized search handle multi processing. I don't know about the details of the pickling.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that isn't the whole code, and I don't see how you can be sure the rest is definitely not related. We need a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you want us to debug this for you. Or we need you to do the debugging steps we ask for if you want to debug it yourself. Otherwise you're just asking for magic.

Comment: If I had to throw out a wild guess, you're either (1) reusing the same name for a class and a variable at module level, (2) using an `import … as` with an ambiguous name as the target, or (3) using a `from … import *` and therefore implicitly doing either of the above.